# Segmentation Fault running wxPython 4.20 on macOS Monterey with Python 3.9 or 3.10

Tags: python, macos, wxpython

I am trying to use wxPython 4.2.0  I have python 3.9.12 and 3.10.7 on my system and the results are identical with both.  It's a 2021 MacBook Pro with an M1 chip.

I cannot run even the simplest app as my regular user, it fails on `import wx` with a segmentation fault.  If I run under `sudo` it works perfectly.

I have a large codebase but this happens with even the simplest example:

```
import faulthandler
faulthandler.enable()
import wx

app = wx.App(False) 
frame = wx.Frame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "Hello World") 
frame.Show(True)    
app.MainLoop()
```

The output from fault handler is:

```
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1173 in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 565 in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007 in _find_and_load
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wx/core.py", line 12 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007 in _find_and_load
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wx/__init__.py", line 17 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007 in _find_and_load
  File "/Users/garethsimpson/test.py", line 5 in <module>
[1]    63037 segmentation fault  python3.9 test.py
```

This was working on my now-dead intel MacBook.

For completeness.  I have just tried a homebrew install of python 3.9 and got the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone finds this question, there was no answer. Wiping my machine and reinstalling fixed it but it’s not clear why.